# Apache2 - Header directives are not working

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, headers

I would like to enhance the security of my server, so I'm following a [guide](https://geekflare.com/apache-web-server-hardening-security/) regarding server security. I'm new to the subject, therefore there are many things I struggle to understand and there is much to change in the configuration files.
At the moment, I am trying to set cookies with `HttpOnly` and `Secure` flags and unset the `X-Powered-By` header, therefore I added these directives `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf`:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
Header always unset X-Powered-By
```

In order to test the directive, I created a simple PHP file where I set a cookie and the header, but what I receive is neither `HttpOnly` nor `Secure`, moreover I'm still receiving the header.
There's a `headers.load` file inside the `mods-enabled` folder, I also checked whether `mod_headers` was enabled with `apache2ctl -M`, which returned (among the others)

```
headers_module (shared)
```

I even tried to manually load the module with `LoadModule` and logs told me the module was already enabled, so I guess everything is fine on that side. 
Please note that I have a virtual host configured as:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName example.com
                ServerAlias www.example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.org/privkey.pem
        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName example.com
                ServerAlias www.example.com
                Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

On the basis of what I've read on the docs, it should inherit the server configuration where not specified otherwise, anyway I tried placing those directives in the VirtualHost configuration and nothing worked.
I'm using `Apache/2.4.29`, my configuration file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. I'm sure I'm making stupid mistakes, but as I said I'm a novice!

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not sure what happened over the night, cookies are now HttpOnly and Secure, I swear to god I did not change anything... The header is still there though. Maybe this helps, the directive `Header always set X-Powered-By. "Computers"` works.